# Material Design React Responsive Cards

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-design

Hi Im new to Material Design, Im trying to make the cards section responsive using media queries and flex. For some reason when the card switches to the column only a part of the image shows and the rest of the card like the text no longer shows. Im finding it very confusing making the components responsive. Am I missing something?

```
const renderCard = (card, index) => {
    
    return (
      
            <>
            
            <Card elevation={6} key = {index} className='services-card'>
            <CardMedia className ='services-card-img' image={card.img}/>
            <CardHeader title={card.title}/>
            <CardContent>
                <Divider className='services-card-divider'/>
                <p>
                    {card.desc}
                </p>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
        </>
        )
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
            <h1 className='title-black-red'>Services</h1>
            </div>
        <div className='services'>
           {data.map(renderCard)}
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}


.services {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 20px 0px 150px 0px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .services {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .services-card {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: green;
  }
}

.services-card {
  height: 80%;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.services-card-divider {
  color: red;
}
.services-card-img {
  height: 180px;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add background-size style to your images

```
 background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `CardMedia` component and this component has `img`. So try to apply the following styles for the image:

```
img {
    max-width:100% !important;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So The actual issue was that my div (which contains the cards) had a set height, and so the cards could not fit properly. Fixing this by setting the height to 100% was enough. Thank you all for your suggestions.